# Two suites cannot have the same name in excel testng while using excel to drive my test class

Tags: testng

> Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException:  Two suites
>   cannot have the same name:    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.checkSuiteNamesInternal(TestNG.java:1019)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.checkSuiteNames(TestNG.java:1012)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.sanityCheck(TestNG.java:985)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)   at
>   net.randomsync.testng.excel.ExcelTestNGRunner.run(ExcelTestNGRunner.java:98)
>     at Runner.MyRunner1.getXmlSuites(MyRunner1.java:44)     at
>   net.randomsync.testng.excel.ExcelTestNGRunner.run(ExcelTestNGRunner.java:83)
>     at Runner.MyRunner.main(MyRunner.java:20)

I'm trying to pass the test methods name from excel file to testng. But the error appears in the eclipse console while I tries to run the runner class.
My runner class:

```
ExcelTestNGRunner runner=new ExcelTestNGRunner("path to excel file");

    runner.setPreserveOrder(true);
    runner.setVerbose(1);


    runner.run();
```

My excel file:

```
Suite Name           suitename
Suite Parameters    

Id                   Test Configuration
1                    classes=packagename.classname
```

Comment: Please check my solution for making your TestNG suites more DRY https://stackoverflow.com/a/51666801/4165898

Answer (score 0):

excel-testng parses each worksheet in the excel file as a separate suite and passes them on to testng.run(). From the exception thrown, it seems that there was more than 1 suite with same name.

Can you make sure that there are no other worksheets in the input excel file with same suite name?