# Is it possible to run two suites with the same name in testng?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a scenario where i have a a suite name e.g Devices (contains all the devices test cases) and it belongs to Browser Suites Chrome, IE and Firefox. The browser suites belong to testng.xml suite. See image below[image]

The problem i have is when i run testng.xml, i get the error "Two suites cannot have the same name: Devices Suite", is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Please check my solution for making your TestNG suites more DRY https://stackoverflow.com/a/51666801/4165898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have two suites with the same name, that's correct, by design. In case if you want the shown arch, you should run one suite on each browser, it will look like (assuming we are giving driver names in `parameter` for running test with needed drivers):

```
<test name="Firefox">
    <parameter name="driver" value="firefoxdriver" />
    <classes>
        <class name="testNG.Registration"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Chrome">
    <parameter name="driver" value="chromedriver" />
    <classes>
        <class name="testNG.Registration"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: Thanks, i know your way will work just wanted to know if there is a budge  to overcome this issue.

Comment: The thing is suit names are counted as some kind of unique identifiers in testng, that's why it's impossible by design :)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.