# TestNG run method once for all test suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, testng

```
//deleted, see a refactoring at Update section.
```

I have this piece of code I wrote for an example.
When **@BeforeClass** annotation presents it sets the value to be what I expect it to be and the inheriting TestsOther class prints it correctly.
**But** it runs **testInit** method each time , once for **SomeTest** and once for **OtherTest**.

So the obvious thing I thought to do is to change it to **@BeforeTest** annotation, so it would evaluate that method only once, before all tests, but then my inheriting TestsOther class gets **null**.

Can someone explain to me why it gets a null and what is the right way to make **testInit** method run only once for all the suite.

Thanks.

**Update:**
To make it more clear I have refactored the code a little.

```
    public class TestsInit {

    protected String value;

    @BeforeClass
    public void testInit(){
        System.out.println("Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.");
        value="Something";
    }

    @Test
    public void SomeTest(){
        boolean isTrue=true;
        System.out.println("Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.");
        Assert.assertTrue(isTrue);
    }
}

public class TestsOther extends TestsInit {

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"SomeTest"})
    public void OtherTest(){
        System.out.println("Entered OtherTest test in TestsOther class with value: "+value);
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
Entered OtherTest test in TestsOther class with value: Something
```

I want to look like this:

```
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
Entered OtherTest test in TestsOther class with value: Something
```

So it will run the testInit method only once, and run the SomeTest test once before the TestsOther test.
I need to store the value at parent class so all children can use it.
I need to run the testInit only once and the SomeTest test only once also.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you please update the imports also?

Comment: @AnujTeotia its nothing special , import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

Comment: @AnujTeotia using TestNG and some Spring libs.

Comment: Everything looks correct to me. Let me check this on my end :)

Comment: Please check my solution for making your TestNG suites more DRY https://stackoverflow.com/a/51666801/4165898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I have taken your own code as it is as follows:

`TestsInit` Class:

```
package Q45436872;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestsInit 
{

    protected String value;

    @BeforeClass
    public void testInit(){
    System.out.println("Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.");
    value="Something";
    }

    @Test
    public void SomeTest(){
    boolean isTrue=true;
    System.out.println("Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.");
    Assert.assertTrue(isTrue);
    }
}
```

`TestsOther` Class:

```
package Q45436872;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestsOther  extends TestsInit
{

    @Test (dependsOnMethods = {"SomeTest"})
    public void OtherTest(){
    System.out.println("Entered OtherTest test in TestsOther class with value: "+value);
    }
}
```

`testng.xml`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="Q45436872.TestsInit"/> 
       <class name="Q45436872.TestsOther"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Now when I run this setup as a `TestNG Suite` I do get the following result:

```
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
Entered OtherTest test in TestsOther class with value: Something

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

I think till here we are on the same page.

### Requirement:

Now, your requirement seems to:

1. Run the `testInit` method only once.
2. Run the `SomeTest` test once before the `TestsOther` test

### Solution:

As solution, I just commented out the mandatory execution of `TestsInit` Class. So my updated `testng.xml` was as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
 <!--       <class name="Q45436872.TestsInit"/>  -->
       <class name="Q45436872.TestsOther"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

So now I am only executing `TestsOther` Class. `TestsOther` Class `extends TestsInit`. So as `testInit()` is within `@BeforeClass` annotation this method gets executed first.

Next, `SomeTest()` under `@Test` annotation gets executed which was inline with your requirement.

Finally, `OtherTest()` method under `@Test` annotation from `TestsOther` Class gets executed (which was tagged as `(dependsOnMethods = {"SomeTest"})`), which is again inline with your requirement.

The output on my console is:

```
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
Entered OtherTest test in TestsOther class with value: Something
```

This output exactly matches to your requirement.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I need to test it and I will update you and the topic.

Comment: Thank you , this is what I have looked for. Chosen as an answer!

Comment: @MarkDavydov Glad to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Both classes have tests, so they are test classes and `@BeforeClass` will be run once by class.
With `@BeforeTest`, you see `null` because you have 2 instances but the method is only called on 1 instance (the other will have `null` value).

If you want to have only one call of the method without `null`, you need to store and find the value from the `ITestContext`.

```
@BeforeTest
public void testInit(ITestContext context) {
    context.setAttribute("value", "Something");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"SomeTest"})
public void OtherTest() {
    System.out.println(context.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

**Adding a sample that explains the static variable usage**

```
public class TestsInit {
    protected String value;
    private static boolean initialised = false;

    @BeforeClass
    public void testInit() {
        synchronized (TestsInit.class) {
            if (initialised) {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.");
            value = "Something";
            initialised = true;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void SomeTest() {
        boolean isTrue = true;
        System.out.println("Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.");
        Assert.assertTrue(isTrue);
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing I want it to get initialized once at the parent class so every other child class that extends it could use it. That way it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, the example I gave is more abstract than that, they values are not really Strings and have more difficult logic behind em'.

Comment: What you want is not possible: you have 2 `TestsInit` instances but you want only init one. The only solution is using the context or a static variable.

Comment: I have updated the question, if you can take a look please , though I think you already got what I'm trying to do , according to your last answer .

Comment: I have added a static to value and to testInit method , it really helped , now it enteres testInit only once and I get the right value.

Any suggestions how I can avoid to run the parent SomeTest test twice?

Comment: Move the test methods in another subclass.

Answer (score 1):

As `@BeforeClass` runs once by class and there are two classes in your scenario so it will run twice.

**Output with `@BeforeClass` Annotation**

```
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
Entered OtherTest test in TestsOther class with value: Something
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
PASSED: SomeTest
PASSED: OtherTest
PASSED: SomeTest

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

If you want to run **TestsInit** only once, then replace `@BeforeClass` to `@BeforeSuite`

**Output with `@BeforeSuite` Annotation**

```
Entered testInit in TestsInit class,to set the value.
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
Entered OtherTest test in TestsOther class with value: Something
Entered SomeTest in TestsInit class.
PASSED: SomeTest
PASSED: OtherTest
PASSED: SomeTest

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Notice one thing that **SomeTest** is running twice, it is because TestsOther is a different class which is extending TestsInit class and it has only one method which has a dependency on SomeTest testcase.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't get what I need to do to make SomeTest run only once?

Answer (score 0):

To execute  **testInit** method only once for all classes , try to do initialization part in separate abstract class and extends other classes with this class where required.

If you are receiving output like this

> Something
>
> PASSED: SomeTest
>
> PASSED: OtherTest

According to understanding, **@Test** of parent class will run before **@Test** of current child class. since you have **@Test** in both classes, so in each class **@Test** is executed and print on console.

With **@BeforeTest** annotation, it is working fine as well.(this means i did'nt get **null** on this change)

Can you please share some more code if you are still getting null after this proposed solution.

Comment: I have updated the question to make the question more clear, I have showed there what output I want to get.