# How to force TestNG to execute the Same Suite.xml file multiple times with different parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, testng

I have a TestNG enabled SpringBoot gradle project.
In the testng tests, I have a requirement of calling the same suite XML files from 2 different XML files like below.

In FirstTest.xml:

```xml
<suite-files>
   <parameter name="TestParam" value="FirstTest"/>
   <suite-file path="Common.xml"/>
   <suite-file path="Test1.xml"/>
</suite-files>
```

in SecondTest.xml:

```xml
<suite-files>
   <parameter name="TestParam" value="SecondTest"/>
   <suite-file path="Common.xml"/>
   <suite-file path="Test2.xml"/>
</suite-files>
```

I have an AllTest.xml which calls both FirstTest.xml and SecondTest.xml:

```xml
<suite-files>
   <suite-file path="FirstTest.xml"/>
   <suite-file path="SecondTest.xml"/>
</suite-files>
```

Instead of `@Parameters`, I'm using ITestContexts to get all parameters in the `@BeforeClass` annotated method of Common.java, Test1.java, and Test2.java classes to read the parameter passed from the Suite files.

```java
protected Map<String, String> params;
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void init(ITestContext ctx) {
  params = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getAllParameters();
}

/* 
Other data Preparation methods in case of Common 
and Test methods in case of Test1 & Test2 classes 
based on params.get("TestParam") value
*/
```

Based on this parameter, the Data Preparation takes place in the Common.java class and is stored in the local cache. In the Test1 and Test2 classes again based on this parameter, respective data created in Common.java is retrieved from the cache.

Now, when I execute AllTest.xml, the Common.xml gets executed only once from the FirstTest.xml and it is being skipped in the SecondTest.xml
I want to execute Common.xml file multiple times from different suite files (FirstTest.xml, SecondTest.xml, ... up to NthTest.xml)

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.